# compare two times in php

Tags: php, time, strtotime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare two time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403858/how-to-compare-two-time-in-php)

Hi I am new in time functions in php, i have,

```
@$download_time = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $dec_time);
$current_time = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');    
$diff = abs(strtotime($current_time) - strtotime($download_time));    
$time=65 // $time is in seconds
```

Now I want to compare if ($diff < $time) how can I compare with this two values.

Comment: Please make sure to always try the search feature before posting a new question. Chances are your problem has been encountered before and a satisfactory answer already exists. This particular question has been asked and answered thousands of times before. Good luck!

Comment: thanx i will do from next...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$dec_time` is a **unix timestamp**, then simply:

```
if (time() - $dec_time < $time) {/* ... */}
```

Else if it is a textual representation:

```
if (time() - strtotime($dec_time) < $time) {/* ... */}
```

Be aware of using needless variables if it's doesn't needed later, because you can save a lot of memory if keep an eye of this. If the server's PHP version is above 5.2, then you can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class wich gives you a lot of extended functionality.

I didn't understood why is the `abs()` because the download time should be at the past.

**Notice:**
Keep the `@`'s away from your code, because it costs a lot of additional calculations for the PHP interpreter, maybe it is longer to type, but test if the variable exists before, like:

```
if (!empty($dec_time) && time() - strtotime($dec_time) < $time) {/* ... */}
```