# Comparing time in PHP

Tags: php, time

I am comparing a deadline time from my database which is on a 24-hour format (like 3:00 = 15:00) to the time now.

For example, if a student wasn't able to submit on the due time, an upload link will be greyed out.

I'm okay with the date comparison, my problem is the time.

Here's my current code:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = strtotime(date('G:i:s'));
$deadtime = strtotime($r['upload_deadtime']);

/*------$deadtime = 15:00:00 ---------*/

if(date($r['upload_deadline']) >= $date && $deadtime > $time){

echo '<td><a href="stud_prep.php">upload</a></td>';                 
}
else{
echo '<td><a title="your too late! haha!" style="color:grey">upload</a></td>';  
}
```

Update: let's just forget about the date comparison, what I'm trying to say is how can I compare my deadline time (which is on a 24-hour format (like 3:00:00 = 15:00:00)) to the time now.

Here's my current code:

```
$time = strtotime(date('G:i:s')); /*which returns 23:15:42 instead of 14:15:42 */
$deadtime = strtotime('15:00:00');


if($deadtime > $time){

echo '<td><a href="stud_prep.php">upload</a></td>';                 
}
else{
echo '<td><a title="your too late! haha!" style="color:grey">upload</a></td>';  
}
```

Comment: Can you print out the dates you are comparing first and verify you are getting what you want? Not sure why there are two comparisons that must be met if you just need to verify that the time of posting is less than current time.

Comment: What is the value of `$r['upload_deadline']`?

Comment: And whatever value it holds, this comparison is not right `date($r['upload_deadline']) >= $date`

Comment: I got your point that you need to compare only time not date and `strtotime` will convert it in unix timestamp which is considered from January 1,1970! So you need only time without date!! Please try this answer on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13391515/2679536)

Comment: `/*which returns 23:15:42 instead of 14:16:42 */` did you set Timezone?

Comment: your timezone is GMT+8, i.e. philippines time and date function gives you US server time! `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');`

Comment: what? I did not know this. how can I change this bro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

$deadtime = strtotime("15:00:00");

if ($deadtime - time() > 0){
  echo '<td><a href="stud_prep.php">upload</a></td>';                 
}else{
  echo '<td><a title="your too late! haha!" style="color:grey">upload</a></td>';  
}
```

This may solve your time comparison issue!!

`strtotime("15:00:00")` will convert time into unix timestamp of today's 15:00:00 and `time()` have current unix timestamp.

Comment: bro it added 3 hours in our time. i guess i'll just explode then minus 3 and then implode it. what do you think?

Comment: added 3 hours? what do you want to explode and implode? what's your timezone? I think it's timezone issue nothing else!

Comment: Its Asia/Manila. I've pasted that date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); in my code. but it added 3 hours in our time.

Comment: heres what im talking about

 `$time = date('G:i:s');
 
 list($hours,$mins,$secs) = explode(":",$time);
    $hours  = date("G") - 3;


 $time_array = array($hours,$mins,$secs);
 $new_time =implode(":",$time_array);
 
 echo "<br />".$new_time;`

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');` shows me time `15:57:08`. I think it's your current time, right? And the way you're talking about is a very long way!! If you need to compare only hour, just take only hour `date('G')` and compare it with '15' like `if(date('G')-15 > 0)`

Comment: no i need the whole time set. but I got it right now

Answer (score 0):

You just have the comparison backwards on your time check.

You are checking if the deadline date is in the future (assuming the script always runs in the present) and then you are checking that the deadline time is less than the current time (IE before), on a date time epoch value.

With the check you are doing on the strtotime, you do not need to check the dates, as they are already included with the date and time by means of epoch.

Simply do:

```
if($deadtime > $time){
echo '<td><a href="stud_prep.php">upload</a></td>';                 
} else {
echo '<td><a title="your too late! haha!" style="color:grey">upload</a></td>';  
}
```

This will only show the upload link in the table if the deadline time is in the future.

EDIT:

In the case of your new code, you just need to make the deadtime a strtotime of the deadline date and time stamp from your dBase. Then the code will work.
You are still also comparing the wrong way around!

Example:

```
/* deadtime = strtotime of datetimestamp in format yyyy-mm-dd G:i:s */
/* $time = strtotime of now. */
if($deadtime > $time){
echo '<td><a href="stud_prep.php">upload</a></td>';                 
} else {
echo '<td><a title="your too late! haha!" style="color:grey">upload</a></td>';  
}
```

Comment: haha oh i forgot. but i tested it with "<". doesn't work either

Comment: That will be because your deadtime needs to be a date time stamp value that has had strtotime() ran on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use time [PHP's DateTime::Diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
// Current Date and Time
$date_time_now = new DateTime();

// Date Time values from DB (Assuming it's coming from database)
$date_time_deadline = new DateTime('2014-09-08 15:00:00');


// Calculate difference
$difference = $date_time_now->diff($date_time_deadline);

// Output difference in human-readable format
echo "Difference: " . $difference->format('%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working code. I think you'll know that my point is.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$time = date('H:i:s');
$deadline_time = date("h:i a",strtotime($r['upload_deadtime']));

list($hours,$mins,$secs) = explode(":",$time);
$hours  = date("H") + 9;/*-gives me wrong hours so i got to modify it-*/

$time_array = array($hours,$mins,$secs);
$new_time =implode(":",$time_array);

$deadtime = strtotime($deadline_time);
$time_now = strtotime($new_time);

if($r['upload_deadline'] < $date && $deadtime < $time_now){/*-compares the date and time-*/

echo '<td><a  href="stud_prep.php">upload</a></td>';

}
else{
echo '<td><a title="your too late! haha!" style="color:grey">upload</a></td>';  
}
```