# How to compare two dates in php and echo newer one?

Tags: php

**How to compare two dates in php and echo newer one?**

My dates are in the following format: `date("F j, Y, g:i a");` which give us `August 12, 2011, 9:45 am`.

My dates are as follow:

- date 1 `$created`
- date 2 `$updated` / if no updated have been made value is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/php-compare-date

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("August 12, 2011, 9:45 am");
$date2 = new DateTime("August 12, 2011, 10:45 am");

$never_date = ($date1<$date2)?$date1:$date2;

echo $never_date->format("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

But note, that `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is a valid input for `DateTime()`, but will not work as expected. It will result in a `-0001-11-30 00:00:00` (at least for PHP 5.3-VC9-nts on Win7 x64).

**Update:** I see two options for workarouning that `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

- Allow nulls in that column in your DB and remove `DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00`.
- Check if `$updated == '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` and if so, just return `$created`:
- Check if `$updated == ''` (empty string) and if so return `$created`:

  ```
  if ($updated=='0000-00-00 00:00:00' || $updated=='')
      $never_date = $created;
  else
      $never_date = ($created<$updated)?$created:$updated;
  ```

I doubt that it's right behaviour to show `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for a record that was never updated.

Comment: @JOHN - how to do it without knowing in front values of the dates? E.G there will be saved in the DB

Comment: DateTime receive any valid date string. See
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: @John - Is there any walk around this? `$never_date` currently returning `November 30, -0001, 12:00 am`.

Comment: @NewUser It depends on whether `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is greater or lesser than `$date1` as per your business logic.

Comment: @John - if/else statement will be perfect for this situation. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date to timestamp:

```
if (strtotime($created) > strtotime($updated))
{
// ...
}
else
{
// ...
}
```