# Compare dates to display only future events: PHP

Tags: php

I have the date in is this format:

```
June 22, 2012
```

Using PHP's date function I am getting the date like so:

```
date("F j, Y")
```

Using an if statement I compare the two hoping to eliminate all of those dates which have already passed:

```
if(date("F j, Y") > $date)
```

However, it works but leaves all but one date:

```
February 14, 2012
```

Can someone explain why or tell me a better way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038484/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php-and-echo-newer-one?lq=1

Comment: Don't compare strings, you'll get silly stuff like `Feb 2012` being greater than `Dec 2012`, because F comes after D in the alphabet. Compare native PHP timestamps - simple integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

date() returns a string, so in your case its only returns strings that are greater than the literal string "June 22, 2012".  Try using [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) on your date() call, e.g

```
$today = strtotime($todays_date);
```

This will take the time string returned by date() and convert it to unix timestamp, which you can use to compare dates.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its amazing what you overlook when your tired!