# Php Date and Time Comparision

Tags: php, date, time

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/php-compare-date) question but time format is different

I have following date format `Tue, 11 Sep 2012 17:38:09 GMT`
in `$pubDate` variable

I would like to compare `$pubDate`  with current Date and Time to see if `Tue, 11 Sep 2012 17:38:09 GMT` is in last 10 mins or not

EDIT:

I have tried

```
//get current time
                strtotime($pubDate);
                time() - strtotime($pubDate);
                if((time()-(60*10)) < strtotime($pubDate)){
                    //if true increase badge by one
                    $badge = $badge + 1;
                }
```

it gives the warning:
It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /Users/xxxxx/Desktop/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.php on line 26

EDIT:

I have added `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` line to my php and now

```
$inDate  = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, $pubDate);
    $postDate = new DateTime();

    $diff = $inDate->diff( $postDate);

    // If the total number of days is > 0, or the number of hours > 0, or the number of minutes > 10, then its an invalid timestamp.
    if( $diff->format( '%a') > 0 || $diff->format( '%h') > 0 || $diff->format( '%i') > 10) {
     die( 'The timestamps differ by more than 10 minutes');
    }
```

works without warning, Thanks everyone

Comment: So... did you call the `date_default_timezone_set()` function then?

Comment: On a side note it would be easier if you compare `strtotime($pubDate)` to `strtotime('-10 minutes')`....

Comment: @veredesmarald I didnt call `date_default_timezone_set()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) to do the comparison:

```
$format = 'D, d M Y H:i:s O';
$tz = new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York');

// Create two date objects from the time strings
$pubDate  = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, 'Tue, 11 Sep 2012 17:38:09 GMT', $tz);
$postDate = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, 'Tue, 11 Sep 2012 17:38:09 GMT', $tz);

// Compute the difference between the two timestamps
$diff = $pubDate->diff( $postDate);

// If the total number of days is > 0, or the number of hours > 0, or the number of minutes > 10, then its an invalid timestamp.
if( $diff->format( '%a') > 0 || $diff->format( '%h') > 0 || $diff->format( '%i') > 10) {
    die( 'The timestamps differ by more than 10 minutes');
}
```

You can play around with it and see it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/2hGH9e).

Comment: +1 for using `DateTime` instead of the old `date` and `time` functions

Comment: Florent, thanks for the tip. I typically avoid the constructor, I'm not sure why. And thanks Havelock, the DateTime class is a gem that is mostly undiscovered.

Comment: You loose the potential of DateTime comparing each element with strings. Use DateTime +1, your `if` -100

Comment: @Maks3w - What element is being compared with strings?

Comment: @nickb The output of ->format is a string. You transform from string to DateTime to convert again to string and compare

Comment: Because DateTime is parsing the times into the sub-categories of the time. Your answer, besides not being functional, is only subtracting time off the current time, and isn't using the input string format.

Comment: It works but I am still getting the WARNING  `It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /Users/`

Comment: @Mord - That is a valid timezone identifier. You should see if passing the timezone to DateTime fixes this, I'll update my answer.

Comment: You need to set the timezone in php.ini

Comment: and also how can I get current time automatically from system on line `$postDate = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, 'Tue, 11 Sep 2012 17:48:09 GMT');`

Comment: @Mord - Use `$postDate = new DateTime();`, that's the current system date.

Comment: @nickb I have already tried that it gives `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct():` I guess i have to find a way to change php.ini settings as Maks3w said

Comment: @Mord - No, that'll work, you just have some other error message that's being suppressed or not posted. Catch the exception and print the message, then fix the problem that it says. It might be because you need a timezone: `$postDate = new DateTime( "now", $tz);`, where `$tz` is copied from above.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare two DateTime objects.

```
$nowLessTenMinutes = new DateTime();
$nowLessTenMinutes->sub(new DateInterval('PT10M')); // Sub 10 minutes

if ($myTime >= $nowLessTenMinutes);
```

Comment: This answer is more PHP 5.3 style

Comment: How can this work, the parameters to the `if` are `integer >= object`. It fails with `Notice: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int`, as expected.

Comment: $myTime is a DateTime object. I omitted how to pass from string to DateTime. I think that we shouldn't give full answers and give hints

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime::diff()](http://php.net/datetime.diff.php) to calculate the difference:

```
$input = new DateTime( 'Tue, 11 Sep 2012 17:38:09 GMT' );
$now = new DateTime();

/* calculate differences */
$diff = $input->diff( $now );

echo $diff->format( '%H:%I:%S' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, if you are using MAMP or similar thing it will be complicated to change php.ini  try to add `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` on top of your php file.

Then most of the other answers on this thread should work.