# How can I tell if a datetime field in MySQL is in the past with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm  building a website for a school, with a place the teachers can add assignments.  All these assignments are stored in a MySQL table, with a field of type datetime that stores the due date.  I'm looking for a way, with PHP, to check if the due date is in the past so I can provide visual feedback for the teachers and students.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are several different ways of doing this. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use PHP's date comparison tools.  Here is an example:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = $yourDateFromTheDatabase;
if ($date2 < $date1) {
    //it still has time
} else {
    //time has passed
}
```

Does that help?  You can find more examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 3):

You could actually handle this with MYSQL in your query, which i would find easier because then you don't have to handle dates in php.
For example:

```
SELECT DueDate, (DueDate < CURDATE()) FROM table;
```

(DueDate < CURDATE()) returns 0/1

otherwise:

[Compare given date with today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/php-compare-date)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you're storing dates into the **datetime** field (hopefully you're using TIMESTAMP), you can use the PHP **strtotime** function, which parses the MySQL timestamp into a Unix timestamp which can be used for comparing PHP values. Here's an example:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT datetime FROM assignments;");

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ) {
    $date = date("g:i a F j, Y ", strtotime($row["date"]));
}
```

And do your comparisons with the `$date` variable. That's a super broad and rough look at an idea, but hopefully it helps somewhat.

You can read more about this concept [here](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/10/05/how-to-convert-mysql-timestamp-to-php-date-type/).

Good luck!