# PHP compare two dates

Tags: javascript, php, html, date

I have two dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD and I want to compare them do do some task.

I tried this piece of code:

```
         $temp_date = strtotime($cu['date']);
         $temp_upto = strtotime($upto_date);

         if($temp_date <= $temp_upto){
            echo "<tr id='highlight'>"; 
        }else{
            echo "<tr>";
            }
```

`$cu` is an array and contains date in the same format. Is this the correct way to compare dates in php?
The output which I get is quite weird! I haven't posted the full code because its too long and irrelevant for this question.
Thanks!.

**UPDATE:** So this is what I am trying to do. I have many normal dates and I have a upto date if the normal dates are less than or equal to upto date then I want the id="highlight" added to . THe whole thing is inside a loop for some other purpose of my code.

I echoed the dates like this:

```
 echo "DATE: " . $temp_date + " UPTO: " . $upto_date;
```

and the output was something like

```
DATE: 1349042400 UPTO: 00-00-0000
DATE: 1349388000 UPTO: 00-00-0000
DATE: 1352588400 UPTO: 00-00-0000
DATE: 1352761200 UPTO: 00-00-0000
DATE: 1353193200 UPTO: 00-00-0000
DATE: 1353366000 UPTO: 1353193200
DATE: 1354143600 UPTO: 1353193200
DATE: 1354662000 UPTO: 1353193200
```

still the comparison doesn't happen. and I dont see any change!

People who are suggestion already answered questions, I have already read and implemented most of them without any success.

**UPDATE 2:** While I am still trying to figure out my issue. I want to share the expanded code snippet here http://pastebin.com/nsVGV9dg

Comment: if you compared the strtotime values directly, it'd work. those are simple integers and `>`/`<`/`=` type comparisons work as expected. You're converting to strings, in a least-significant-value-first ordering, so your comparisons are garbage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Compare Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/php-compare-date) And all these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is%3Aquestion+%5Bphp%5D+compare+dates

Answer (score 4):

Nope, this isn't right. You're comparing two date strings. You want to compare the timestamps instead:

```
$temp_dateTS = strtotime($cu['date']);
$temp_uptoTS = strtotime($upto_date);

if ($temp_dateTS <= $temp_uptoTS) {
    # code...
}
```

This is also possible (and better) if you use `DateTime` class:

```
$temp_date = new DateTime($cu['date']);
$temp_upto = new DateTime($upto_date);

if ($temp_date <= $temp_upto) {
    # code...
}
```

Comment: please check update in my question..I get this error when I use DateTime...Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int

Comment: @user2933671: That's not how you concatenate strings in PHP. Use `.` instead of `+`. Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: @MikeB Yes you are right! there are quite a lot of answers to such an question and I am trying to implement them in my code since an hour now!. I am trying just to find why the hell my comparison doesn't work even if the method is correct!

Comment: @AmalMurali I have updated my echo call in OP. I will try to share more of my code in few minutes because I will have to clear aup some unnecessary junk

Answer (score 3):

I'm not directly answering your question but I thinks it's better to user php `DateTime` object.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

Comment: He isn't calculating the time difference anywhere.

Comment: He can calculate difference and compare it. Don't see a problem.