# How to compare dates and strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, date, compare

i'm developing a PHP program and i must compare a `date` variable and a `string variable`.
I've tried `strcmp` but it doesn't work...
suggests?
Thank's

Comment: Is the string variable a date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP compare two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008581/php-compare-two-dates)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Best way of comparing dates is using time-stamps :

```
$string = '11/05/2016';//string variable
$date = date('Y-m-d',time());//date variable

$time1 = strtotime($string);
$time2 = strtotime($date);
if($time1>$time2){
    //do this
}
else{
    //do this
}
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: yes `$time1` and `$time2` are integers, so everything which works on integers will work on those.

Comment: But use `===` instead as its faster than `==` and more appropriate. Please mark the answer as accepted for this question if it helped you.

Comment: No Problem. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = strtotime('10/16/2003');

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time); //my date format is Y-m-d,usw your date format
```

there `$newformat` variable also a `date`

this way you can compare `date` and `string`

Comment: This answer is only partial. While it shows how to prepare the string for comparison with a date, it doesn't show how to do the actual comparison, but the question was "how to compare."