# How to sort and echo the values from Multi-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting, multidimensional-array

How can I sort this array by value "date and let the ASC result shows?
Is the bad formatting and naming caused my works to being wrong so that it made the ["date"] could not show in the table by ASC format.
Thanks for everyone helps.

**Array:**

```
$arrayBooking = array(
        "a01"=>array(
            "Amy"=>array(
                "booking1"=>array(
                    "231"=>array(
                        "date"=>"21/08/2014",
                        "period"=>array(
                            "from"=>1,
                            "to"=>3
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
           ),
           "a02"=>array(
              "Peter"=>array(
                "booking1"=>array(
                    "231"=>array(
                        "date"=>"23/08/2014",
                        "period"=>array(
                            "from"=>2,
                            "to"=>3
                            )
                        )
                  ),
                 "booking2"=>array(
                    "231"=>array(
                        "date2"=>"20/08/2014",
                        "period"=>array(
                            "from"=>2,
                            "to"=>5
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            "a05"=>array(
               "Mary"=>array(
                  "booking1"=>array(
                     "321"=>array(
                        "date"=>"22/08/2014",
                            "period"=>array(
                                "from"=>3,
                                "to"=>6
                                )
                            )
                        )
                   )
              )
            )
```

Comment: it is already sorted by `date`

Comment: it showed almost 2% of the array information. lol

Comment: i got it i will try and update you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function to sort array by preferred algorithm

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    if ($a < $b) {
       return -1;
    } elseif ($a == $b) {
       return 0;
    }
    return 1;
});
```

To compare dates, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2113951/1346234) SO answer

```
$stamp1 = strtotime($date1);
$stamp2 = strtotime($date2);

return $stamp1 - $stamp2;
```