# php date comparison methods

Tags: php, date

I need help with comparing two dates in php. The first date I am comparing is today's date and the other comes from the database. I tried using `strtotime` but it only works when the database date is less  than today's date, if the date is greater than today's date I have to compare the whole date, and and `strtotime` does not work in that case.

Eg :

```
<?php
   $today=date('d/m/y');
   $expiry_date=$data['expiry'];
   if(strtotime($expiry_date)<strtotime($today)){ 
      echo "today is greater"; 
   } else {
       echo "expiry is greater";
       // only gives the right result when database result is smaller than today
   } 
?>
```

other method :

```
 $today=date('d/m/y');
   $expiry_date=$data['expiry'];
     if($expiry_date<$today)
       { echo "today is greater"; }
     else
       {echo "expiry is greater";} ?>`  // only gives the right result when database result is greater than today
```

Comment: what does `$data['expiry']` contain?

Comment: What is the date format taken from database.

Comment: There's no reason that `strtotime()` shouldn't work on future timestampst given that the time is in an english date format.

Comment: personally I prefer using mktime() and time() for dates. you can easily convert them to readable formats via Date("l, F d, Y g:ia", $string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method should be the correct one:

```
<?php
   $today=date('d/m/y');
   $expiry_date=$data['expiry'];
   if(strtotime($expiry_date)<strtotime($today)){ 
      echo "today is greater"; 
   } else {
       echo "expiry is greater";
       // only gives the right result when database result is smaller than today
   } 
?>
```

The second one is comparing two strings, but this is a numerical problem. The strtotime function converts the strings to numeric times that can be compared. This SO question shows a lot of examples. [Compare given date with today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/php-compare-date)

If you take each of the variables and do a var_dump, you can see what is being compared. Here is an example:

I manually set $expiry_date, since we don't know what format it is being retrieved in.

```
   $data['expiry'] = '11/12/10';
   var_dump($today, $expiry_date);
   var_dump(strtotime($today), strtotime($expiry_date));
   var_dump($today, strtotime($expiry_date));
```

Results:

```
string(8) "08/09/14" string(8) "11/12/10" 
int(1407567600) int(1289548800) 
string(8) "08/09/14" int(1289548800)
```

I think the most important part here is to figure out what is being retrieved from the database and in what format. First var_dump the variable $expiry_date without modifying it to strtotime. If the format is off even by just dashes or dots instead of slashes, you will get different results. This is show from the [strtotime manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) by sam at frontiermedia dot net dot au

```
<?php 
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11.12.10")); 
// outputs 10th December, 2011 

echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11/12/10")); 
// outputs 12th November, 2010 

echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11-12-10")); 
// outputs 11th December, 2010  
?>
```

Then convert it as necessary to resemble the date variable for today ('d/m/y'), then convert both to strtotime and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your today date format and database date format will be same...

```
$today=date('dd/mm/yyyy'); // DD/MM/YYYY (you are using d/m/y here )
$expiry_date="05/10/2014"; // $data['expiry']; DD/MM/YYYY Make sure for this format also

        if(strtotime($expiry_date)<strtotime($today)){
            echo "today is greater";
        } else {
            echo "expiry is greater";
            // only gives the right result when database result is smaller than today
        }
```