# Less than operator not wokking in date

Tags: php

Less than operator not working while comparing date

```
   $today="27-02-2015";
$end="24-06-2015";
if($end < $today){
echo "yes";

}else{
echo "no";
}
```

Comment: Has to be a string, "27-02-2015", otherwise you're just doing math. Also, it should be wrapped around "strtotime".

Comment: Still not working after inverted cote

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Compare Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/php-compare-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a string compare here, which does not tell you which date is later/earlier. You could change these dates into DateTime and compare them

```
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '27-02-2015');
$b = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '24-06-2015');

if ($b < $a) {
    echo " do something here";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change the string to format "2015-02-27" - then year is first, then month and you can compare like numbers

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$today=strtotime("27-02-2015");
$end=strtotime("24-06-2015");
if($end < $today){
 echo "yes";

}else{
echo "no";
}
```

Comment: Produces the wrong result (try it out [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/);you have to add this statement `date_default_timezone_set ( 'UTC' );`).

Comment: @collapsar result is okay, it's just warnings.

Comment: @Forien thx. i missed the actual output among the 'warning...' blurb

Answer (score 0):

Build Date objects from string specified in the way your locale settings mandate and compute the differences on epoch millisecond:

```
$s_today = '02/27/2015';
$s_end   = '06/24/2015';

date_default_timezone_set ( 'UTC' );   # required by strtotime. Actual value doesn't matter as you are interested in the date diff only 
$today = strtotime($s_today);
$end   = strtotime($s_end);

if ($end < $today)  {
    echo "less ( $s_today < $s_end )";
} else {
    echo "more ( $s_today > $s_end )";
}
```

***Note***

@n-dru's approach is viable too. It depends which date specs your code fragment must cope with and if you wish to perform more computations on the dates. In the latter case I'd opt  in favor of normalization to the epoch seconds. Otherwise it proabably isn't worth the hassle.