# Change of td color with php if else statement

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to change color of my td as per the date received from the sql query. Please help with following -

I want to change the color of td to green if the fetched date is less than today's date.

```
<?php
    if($mydate > date('d-M-Y'))
    {
        echo "<td style="background-color:green;">";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "<td>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is the value of $mydate variable

Comment: echo "<td style=' background-color:green;' >";? Check your quotes.

Comment: its like 11-sep-2015

Comment: And also you cant compare dates that way.

Comment: changing quote doesn't work

Comment: aldin27 has corrected one part (you did have an error there), but you might want to check your if statement to check you'd actually create the coloured td if it's true.

Comment: you want the fetched date to be less than today but you have the greater than sign `>` in your code

Comment: @CodeGodie your correct. Maybe he's too confused about greater than and less than. lol

Comment: `$mydate` format or value.

Comment: is `$mydate` coming from a database? is it a string or an actual date object? show the code where you declare this

Comment: Post your code where you get `$mydate`

Comment: <?
       while($data=oci_fetch_array($array))

       {
       $idno=$data[0];
       $caseno=$data[1];
       $pname=$data[2];
       $rname=$data[3];       
       $purpose=$data[4];
       $mydate=$data[5];
      ?>

Comment: so `$mydate` is coming from your database. How is it stored in your database? is it of type DATE, DATETIME, .. ?

Comment: also can you `var_dump($data)` inside your `while` loop to see what you have

Comment: its DATETIME in oracle

Comment: if its DATETIME then it is probably stored like this: `2015-09-11  05:57:05` not like this `11-sep-2015`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mydate = "2015-10-01";
if(strtotime($mydate) > strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))
{
    echo "<td style='background-color:green;'>testing</td>";
}
else
{
   echo "<td>testing</td>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. It worked well.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check dates in string formats.

One way you could do that is by formatting dates in UNIX timestamp (so that you have an integer) allowing you to check properly if a date is actually newer or older than another one.

```php
$mydate = (new DateTime($mydate))->format('U');
$date   = (new DateTime(date('Y-m-d')))->format('U');

if($mydate > $date)
{
    echo "<td style='background-color: green;'>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td>";
}
```

Comment: Do not downvote without stating the reason, please.

Comment: explain why this would answer the question

Comment: thanks. looks better

Comment: I can do this in JavaScript, is it not the same in PHP? `if ("2015-09-11" > "2015-09-10") ...`

Comment: PHP does not work that way. @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan: You must convert the date from string to a Date() object to do that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @GiamPy No you do not need to do that if they are both string and both in YYYYMMDD format since the comparison will work on the string values of the digits too

Comment: @mplungjan Yes if the format is like that then no need to convert. PHP will treat them as integer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2114029/295783

Comment: I'd rather have them in an integer or DateTime format although, but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: should be `if($mydate < $date)` since he said _"if the fetched date is less than today's date"_

Comment: @CodeGodie: I have just used what he's given us in the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert your both time to a single format and compare

try following

***I have used `div` instead of `td` for ease of use***

```
<?php
    $mydate="08-sep-2015";
    //$mydate="11-sep-2015";
    $today     = date('d-M-Y');
    $todayTime = strtotime($today);
    $compTime  = strtotime($mydate);
    if($compTime < $todayTime) {
      echo "<div style='background-color:green;'>fgd</div>";
    }
    else{
      echo "<div>sdfsdf</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @RamukTima you need to show us the code to see how you come up with `$mydate`

Comment: @CodeGodie: [He mentioned it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520166/change-of-td-color-with-php-if-else-statement#comment52898083_32520166)

Comment: <?
       while($data=oci_fetch_array($array))

       {
       $idno=$data[0];
       $caseno=$data[1];
       $pname=$data[2];
       $rname=$data[3];       
       $purpose=$data[4];
       $mydate=$data[5];
      ?>

Comment: @GiamPy he did mention it, but i think he is wrong since this is coming from the database, it would probably be stored as `2015-09-11`

Comment: Updated the code please check it

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <table>

    <tr>

      <?php
        $mydate = "2015-10-01";
        if(strtotime($mydate) > strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))
        {
            echo "<td  bgcolor='#FF0000'>testing</td>";
        }
        else
        {
           echo "<td>NOt Green</td>";
        }
        ?>

    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lqh4m7bx/

Comment: yes .Your right.Instead of should i use can not.Sorry for the type.My point that you should use bgcolor instead of background-color:.Any way thanx for your info.

Comment: I meant: you are wrong. The style attribute contains css- it does exactly the same as bgcolor but using 21st century values. I did not refer to spelling mistake

Comment: The HTML bgcolor attribute was deprecated back in 1997 (in W3C HTML 4.0); you should use the CSS background-color style instead.