# What PHP is needed to calculate due date from todays date

Tags: php, datetime, date-difference

I need a few if/elseif/else statements (which I loosely understand) to display different things based on how far away a due date is from today. Example below:

- If due date is > 4 weeks away, priority is low
- If due date is < 4 weeks and > 2 weeks away, priority is medium
- If due date is < 2 weeks and > 1 week away, priority is high
- If due date is < 1 week away, priority is critical

Edited to add: the due date will vary across projects. I am trying to create a project management dashboard. So I am trying to compare `$dt = new DateTime($Project[due_date]);` to `$today = new DateTime();`

When I write out

```
if($dt < $today) {
    echo 'urgent';
} else {
    echo 'high';
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Forgive me if this is a poorly written or newbie question, I am very new to PHP (HTML/CSS is my strength) so I am having a hard time knowing what to even Google to help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare given date with today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/compare-given-date-with-today)

Comment: What your `$Project[due_date]` format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try next code:

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime($Project['due_date']); 

$diff_in_weeks = $dt->diff(new DateTime())->format('%a')/7;

switch (true) {
    case $diff_in_weeks > 4:
        echo 'low';
        break;
    case $diff_in_weeks > 2:
        echo 'medium';
        break;
    case $diff_in_weeks > 1:
        echo 'high';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'critical';
}
```

[PHP online editor](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/48d7aea89030999ac7e5da93079b227b/)